# TF Detect app doesnt work with my own weights

Tags: android, object, mobile, detection, tensorflow

I followed the instruction of object detection android app and successfully run the app using the pretrained tiny-yolo-voc.

Now I have trained another model by myself with my own dataset(1class) using Darknet. Then I convert the weights file to pb type format using the Darkflow command

```
./flow --model cfg/yolo-1class.cfg --load bin/yolo-marker_1class.weights --savepb --verbalise
```

Using the summerize_graph tool, I checked the yolo-marker_1class.pb has the same 'input' and 'output' node.

After i manually copy this pb file into the asset folder and click Run button, I had this error which is not happened when I build when the pretrained tiny-yolo-voc.pb
Can anyone help me please ?[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXsJ3.png)